# logback formatter for Pretty-print JSON

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j, circe

**Objective:** I want my application code to log the non-pretty json as String. That is needed to keep it as one event for Splunk. However, while logging in local, with a different logback.xml if needed, I want it to pretty-print.

**Tried the following:**
I have tried `logstash` and `JacksonJsonFormatter`. Neither seems to be doing the pretty-print. Here are config and sample output:

```
          <encoder class="net.logstash.logch.qos.logback.contrib.jsonback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <fieldNames>
                <timestamp>[ignore]</timestamp>
                <level>[ignore]</level>
                <levelValue>[ignore]</levelValue>
                <thread>[ignore]</thread>
                <logger>[ignore]</logger>
                <version>[ignore]</version>
                <message/>
            </fieldNames>
            <jsonFormatter class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
                <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>
            </jsonFormatter>
            &lt;!&ndash;<layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
                <jsonFormatter class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
                    <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>
                </jsonFormatter>
                <includeContextName>false</includeContextName>
                <appendLineSeparator>false</appendLineSeparator>
            </layout>&ndash;&gt;
        </encoder>

------
Results:
{"message":"{\"interface\":\"dynamodb client\",\"action\":\"test dynamodb connection\",\"status\":\"ok\",\"table-status\":\"ACTIVE\"}"}
```

**Request:**
Can someone suggest the correction in what I am doing here or a good library that provides Encoder and Formatter that pretty-prints a JSON String before logging?

**Code I have**

Code: `logger.info(statusJsonStr);`

logback.xml:

```
<encoder>
  <pattern>%message%n</pattern>
</encoder>
```

Console log looks like this:

```
{"interface":"dynamodb client","action":"test dynamodb connection","status":"ok","table-status":"ACTIVE"}
```

**Libraries in classpath**

```
circe                   = "0.13.0" //for circe-core, circe-parser, circe-jawn
logbackClassic          = "1.2.3" //for  logback-classic & logback-core

    "net.logstash.logback"       % "logstash-logback-encoder" % "4.11",
    "ch.qos.logback.contrib"     % "logback-json-core"        % "0.1.2",
    "ch.qos.logback.contrib"     % "logback-json-classic"     % "0.1.2",
    "ch.qos.logback.contrib"     % "logback-jackson"          % "0.1.2",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core"             % "2.5.2",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind"         % "2.5.2",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-annotations"      % "2.5.2",
```

Answer (score 1):

The following config works for me.

```
<appender name="json" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
        <jsonFormatter
                class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
            <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>
        </jsonFormatter>

        <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSS</timestampFormat>
    </layout>
</appender>
```